# Can a COMReference be fully migrated to PackageReference?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, com, nuget

I am trying to rid myself of a lib-Folder I have in my solution, migrating dlls to nuget and also switching from Packages.config to Packagereference.
That worked well for most dlls.

But now I have some COM-References I am unsure if what I am trying to do is correct.
It looks like this in .csproj:

```
<COMReference Include="MyLib">
  <Guid>{ABCDEFA1-AD1F-AFBE-ACED-AFDF123AADEE}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>X</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>Y</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```

And as a prebuild-event I have

```
<PreBuildEvent>
    regsvr32 /s $(SolutionDir)Lib\MyLib.dll
</PreBuildEvent>
```

Now I am irritated, because I read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#authoring-packages-with-com-interop-assemblies) where it told me to add `ReferencePath` and `EmbedInteropTypes` via `.targets` from the nuget-package.

However I did not get this to work (or it seems it did not suffice in my case (looking at the `GUID` being referenced in the `COMReference`))

So this got me thinking, maybe I do not need to transform this into a Packagereference at all, but just add one (that includes "MyLib"), have the prebuild-event go against that dll from my packages-folder and leave the COMReference as is.

I now just added the libaries I needed to the nuget package I am pulling under `content\x86` and modified the prebuild-event to point to `$([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash('$(NugetPackageRoot)'))` instead.

This seems to work, it builds, and I have no runtime errors (so far), but I am not sure if this is best practice or if I am missing something, any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That prebuild event is minus a thousand elegance points.  Nothing you can do next to get it above zero.  The need to have a decent installer can't be ignored, it is a prerequisite that's not fundamentally different from "you need Windows and .NET".

Comment: @HansPassant cannot disagree on this :) There is a batch file that we use locally on dev machines, but on the server where the builds happen we pretty much need this pre-build event, I only see that I could "hide" it "into" the nuget package but other than that... meh